Replicating brownian distribution of particles
I need to replicate this picture

I need to replicate this drawing
As you can see, this is a representation of the colloidal particles distribution within a solvent. The concentration of particles increases from top to bottom. I was wondering if there is a method to replicate a scheme like this.

Hmm.... Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See minimal working example (MWE) for what needs to go into such a document.

If you don't care about the particles overlapping, you could just draw random sized dots in random locations, but use a weighting on your random function so that more get draw closer to the lower end...

Related: A185423

Here is a "one-liner" in Metapost to give you an idea of what is possible.
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
  for k=1 upto 4000:
    draw (uniformdeviate 120, 1/2 abs(normaldeviate) * 300)
      withpen pencircle scaled (3/2 + 1/2 normaldeviate);
  endfor
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

Compile this with lualatex to get a PDF that looks like this:

I am sure something similar is possible with tikz-pgf random number functions.  If you want the particles not to overlap, then look for answers about Poisson-Disk sampling.  Follow the link above for more information about MetaPost.
